# Что не так c кодом?

Tags: javascript

Почему код всегда выводит "1"?

```
     var userFlatNumber = prompt("Flat number?", "");
     if (1 <= userFlatNumber <= 20) {
         alert("1");
     } else {
         alert("2");
     }
```

Comment: потому что условия так не пишутся. `1 <= x  && x <= 20`

Comment: Спасибо, видимо мой учебник устарел)) В примере: if (0 < a < 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чудеса слабой типизации!

Объясню на примере как работает ваш код, например в первом случае сначала проверяется первое неравенство, `0 < 5 == true`, здесь вроде бы все понятно. Следующий шаг, сравниваем `true > 0`, `true` расценивается как число `1`, `1 > 0 == true`

Второй вариант: `0 > 5 == false`, `false > 0` расценивается как `0 > 0 == false`.

```js
console.log(0 < 5 > 0);
console.log(0 > 5 > 0);
```

Должно быть так)

```js
var userFlatNumber = prompt("Flat number?", "");
if (userFlatNumber >= 1 && userFlatNumber <= 20) {
  alert("1");
} else {
  alert("2");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, видимо мой учебник устарел)) В примере: if (0 < a < 5)

Comment: @ArtemVoloshchuk добавил пояснения